# Using PHP strftime() using date() format string

Tags: php, date, localization, date-format, strftime

I'm maintaining PHP code which seems to mess up date/time handling rather badly. In particular this application does not work well in other locales.

One of the issues is the use of the non-localizable `date()` function instead of the `strftime()` function. It is used several layers deep inside function which are literally used thousands of times with many different format strings all over the place.

Replacing `date()` with `strftime()` would cost way too much time. Rather I'm looking into ways to have `strftime()` handle the same format strings as `date()`, but can't find anything.  Is there any known solution to use `strftime()` with `date()` format strings?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your date output needs to look like?

Comment: If it's "several layers deep", the dates produced by `date` *may* very well be meant for internal use; `date` is a decent way to produce machine readable date formats after all. If the date needs to be presented differently to the user, that should only happen on the "outer layer" anyway. Long story short though: more details with sample values, please.

Comment: Have you looked at using `sed` to find and replace `date()` in all PHP files?

Comment: It's used for both internal and display use, ranging from converting to a Unix timestamp to "may 12, 2013, 12:34" format for use on screen.

Comment: The real problem with this approach is that strftime() is deprecated in PHP 8.1, and is slated to be removed in PHP 9. Using DateTime is not a good option because it also ignores locale and produces only English output. 

The only real solution at this point is to convert to use IntDateFormatter::format(), which *does* use the same format string as date(). It requires the Intl extension to PHP to be installed and enabled, but I suspect that this will soon be universally available unless DateTime is changed to respond to locale.

Answer (score 7):

```
/**
 * Convert strftime format to php date format
 * @param $strftimeformat
 * @return string|string[]
 * @throws Exception
 */
function strftime_format_to_date_format($strftimeformat){
    $unsupported = ['%U', '%V', '%C', '%g', '%G'];
    $foundunsupported = [];
    foreach($unsupported as $unsup){
        if (strpos($strftimeformat, $unsup) !== false){
            $foundunsupported[] = $unsup;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($foundunsupported)){
        throw new \Exception("Found these unsupported chars: ".implode(",", $foundunsupported).' in '.$strftimeformat);
    }
    // It is important to note that some do not translate accurately ie. lowercase L is supposed to convert to number with a preceding space if it is under 10, there is no accurate conversion so we just use 'g'
    $phpdateformat = str_replace(
        ['%a','%A','%d','%e','%u','%w','%W','%b','%h','%B','%m','%y','%Y', '%D',    '%F',   '%x', '%n', '%t', '%H', '%k', '%I', '%l', '%M', '%p', '%P', '%r' /* %I:%M:%S %p */, '%R' /* %H:%M */, '%S', '%T' /* %H:%M:%S */, '%X', '%z', '%Z',
            '%c', '%s',
            '%%'],
        ['D','l', 'd', 'j', 'N', 'w', 'W', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'm', 'y', 'Y', 'm/d/y', 'Y-m-d', 'm/d/y',"\n","\t", 'H', 'G', 'h', 'g', 'i', 'A', 'a', 'h:i:s A', 'H:i', 's', 'H:i:s', 'H:i:s', 'O', 'T',
            'D M j H:i:s Y' /*Tue Feb 5 00:45:10 2009*/, 'U',
            '%'],
        $strftimeformat
    );
    return $phpdateformat;
}
```

I wrote this function because none of the answers above sufficed. Handles most conversions -- easily extendable.

@see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you need to convert the format, that is currently used by `date()` function into a format, that `strftime()` could use.

For that purpose I would suggest using `str_replace()` with arrays as `search` and `replace` arguments:

```
$oldFormat = 'Y-m-d';

$search  = array('Y', 'm', 'd');
$replace = array('%Y', '%m', '%d');

$newFormat = str_replace($search, $replace, $oldFormat);
```

Of course, you should add all the search and replace terms that you would need to convert.

Comment: Nope: apart form `Y`, `m` and `d`, most of the other letters have different meaning between `date()` and `strftime()`. It doesn't make any sense but that's it.

Comment: Just the usually inconsistent PHP, @T30

Answer (score 0):

Example for from date() to strftime(). Thanks Kick_the_BUCKET

```
$search  = array('Y', 'y', 'M', 'm', 'D', 'd');
$replace = array('%Y', '%y', '%B', '%b', '%A %d', '%A %d');

$dateFormat = str_replace($search, $replace, $dateFormat); ?>
echo $dateFormat
```